# Dart List not showing any output

Tags: flutter, date, dart

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main(){
  
  var myD = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(DateTime.now());
  List myList = List.filled(20,false);

   myList.insert(0,myD.toString());
  
  print(myList);
  
}
```

I have written the above code but there is no output or error showing. What is the issue I don't know?

Comment: You should be getting an error about attempting to insert an element into a non-growable `List`.

Answer (score 0):

it should be like this :

```
 var myD ="jhjasashasdh";
 final myList = List<String>.filled(3, "", growable: true);

   myList.insert(0,myD.toString());
  
  print(myList);
}
```